# Export bytea data from Postgres and Import it as blob to Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, postgresql

I have a table with `bytea` column type I need to export this data and import it to similar table in Oracle Db (as blob because there is no bytea type)

Comment: Is your target Oracle DB in cloud?

Comment: No, both are on different servers

Comment: Ora2pg works in both ways? I thought it only works from Oracle to PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

You could use oraclle_fdw, define the empty Oracle table as foreign table in PostgreSQL and move the data with

```
INSERT INTO foreigntab SELECT * FROM localtab;
```

The performance won't be top notch, but it is simple.